# Detect when button is clicked in div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I would like to detect when a button is clicked in a div which has multiple buttons which act like checkboxes for mobile optimized application.

This is what I have as HTML:

[image]

When it was only normal checkboxes instead of button like checkboxes I was able to achieve what I want with this script:

```
$(document).on('change', 'input:checkbox.modifier', function () {
            var totalChecked = $("#modifiersDiv :checkbox:checked").size();
            var maximum = parseInt($('#Maximum').val());
            if (totalChecked === maximum) {
                $("#modifiersDiv :checkbox:not(:checked)").attr("disabled", true);
            } else {
                $("#modifiersDiv :checkbox:not(:checked)").attr("disabled", false);
            }
        });
```

Now I'm trying something like this just to see if the function will be triggered at all but without success:

```
 $(document).on('click', 'input:button.modifier', function () {
                   });
```

Bottom line is that I want to detect with jQuery when 5 buttons are selected then I will need to disable the other buttons in the div until the user will not deselect some button.

### Update

Code I'm using for the button:

```
var startDiv = "<div class='btn-group btn-block' data-toggle='buttons'>";
                            var checkBox = '';
                            $.each(data.modifierOptions, function(key, item) {
                                    checkBox += "<label class='btn btn-checkbox btn-block' style='margin-bottom:2px;'><input type='checkbox' data-quantity='1' class='modifier' data-itemid='" + itemid + "' data-name='" + item.Name + "' data-price='" + item.Price + "' name='" + item.Name + "' value='" + item.ID + "'/>" + item.Name + " </label><br />";
                            });
                            var endDiv = "</div>";
                            var totalDiv = startDiv + checkBox + endDiv;
                            $(totalDiv).appendTo('#modifiersDiv');
```

Comment: I don't see any `input` with type `button` in the HTML you're showing us. Can you give us the HTML you're working on? Also my guess is that you might be using Boostrap to have an `input type button` as checkbox in your code would that be it?

Comment: Could you show the code for the button element?

Comment: code added for button element. @rorofromfrance, yes I'm using bootstrap, thank you

Comment: The code you added still uses `input` w/ type `checkbox` .. why are you trying to tie your click event to an `input:button` then?

Comment: to be able to select multiple options up to n value, pls check screenshot http://i.gyazo.com/ee6388f8d84ff42f8ae72be9535b88bf.png So for example, if 5 buttons are clicked, I want the rest of the buttons in that div to be disabled http://i.gyazo.com/ee6388f8d84ff42f8ae72be9535b88bf.png

Comment: But the click event is defined on input:button and you don't have such an element in Your html...

Comment: At what point do you bind the event handler. Before the new content is generated or after?

Comment: on document ready event. But the checkboxes are generated after the content is generated

Comment: @Laziale, did you have a look at the answer I posted? Not sure if you've already figured out a solution, but the one I posted works properly.

Answer (score 5):

I read over your question, and you weren't far off in your attempt. I put together a pen to demonstrate how you can do this: http://codepen.io/aecend/pen/mjklu

The checkbox inputs aren't being replaced with button elements, the labels are only styled so that they appear to be buttons. In the jQuery, you would still need to use the checkbox selector and instead of disabling the checkboxes themselves (there's no point, they're hidden), simply add the "disabled" class to the other labels once five options are selected.

Here's the HTML I used, I only added the btn-default class to make the buttons more visible:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <title>Hamburger Builder v2.0</title>
</head>
<body class="sitecolor">

<div id="modifiersDiv" class="modal-div" style="width: 250px; margin: 0 auto;">
    You can select a maximum of 5 option(s)
    <br>
    <div class="btn-group btn-block" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-default btn-checkbox btn-block" style="margin-bottom: 2px;">
            <input class="modifier" type="checkbox" value="67739" name="Bacon" data-price="1" data-name="Bacon" data-itemid="a4007375-e037-46ce-be39-57ca2d1872e0" data-quantity="1">
            Bacon
        </label>
        <br>
        <label class="btn btn-default btn-checkbox btn-block" style="margin-bottom: 2px;">
            <input class="modifier" type="checkbox" value="67740" name="Lettuce" data-price="1" data-name="Lettuce" data-itemid="a4007375-e037-46ce-be39-57ca2d1872e1" data-quantity="1">
            Lettuce
        </label>
        <br>
        <label class="btn btn-default btn-checkbox btn-block" style="margin-bottom: 2px;">
            <input class="modifier" type="checkbox" value="67741" name="Tomato" data-price="1" data-name="Tomato" data-itemid="a4007375-e037-46ce-be39-57ca2d1872e2" data-quantity="1">
            Tomato
        </label>
        <br>
        <label class="btn btn-default btn-checkbox btn-block" style="margin-bottom: 2px;">
            <input class="modifier" type="checkbox" value="67742" name="Cheese" data-price="1" data-name="Cheese" data-itemid="a4007375-e037-46ce-be39-57ca2d1872e3" data-quantity="1">
            Cheese
        </label>
        <br>
        <label class="btn btn-default btn-checkbox btn-block" style="margin-bottom: 2px;">
            <input class="modifier" type="checkbox" value="67743" name="Onions" data-price="1" data-name="Onions" data-itemid="a4007375-e037-46ce-be39-57ca2d1872e4" data-quantity="1">
            Onions
        </label>
        <br>
        <label class="btn btn-default btn-checkbox btn-block" style="margin-bottom: 2px;">
            <input class="modifier" type="checkbox" value="67744" name="Pickles" data-price="1" data-name="Pickles" data-itemid="a4007375-e037-46ce-be39-57ca2d1872e5" data-quantity="1">
            Pickles
        </label>
        <br>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

and here is the snippet of JavaScript you'll need, it's almost exactly what you had, except Bootstrap-ready now:

```
$(document).on('change', 'input:checkbox.modifier', function () {
    var totalChecked = $("#modifiersDiv :checkbox:checked").size();
    var maximum = 5; //parseInt($('#Maximum').val())
    if (totalChecked === maximum) {
        $(this).parent().siblings(":not(.active)").addClass("disabled");
    } else {
        $("#modifiersDiv label.disabled").removeClass("disabled");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to the selected buttons, and on each click count the number of buttons that are checked at that moment:

```
$(".button:not(.selected)").click(function(){
   $(this).addClass("selected");
   if($(".button.select").length>4){
      $(".button").addClass("disabled");
   }
}
```

You might want to add something that will also de-select a button once it's clicked twice...

Answer (score 0):

Try this :))))

```
var count=0;
$("#modifiersDiv").find(".modifier").click(function(){

   if($(this).is(":checked")){
    count++;
   }else{
    count--;
  }  

  if(count>=$('#Maximum').val())
   $("#modifiersDiv").find(".modifier").not(':checked').attr("disabled", true);
  else    
   $("#modifiersDiv").find(".modifier").not(':checked').attr("disabled", false);
  });
```